# How to get media count of a user by username on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/lookup/api-reference/get-users-by-username-username
I found this document for getting user info by username, but I want to get media count as well. Can anyone help me how to get it?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the number of media posts that the user has made? That is not a part of the API.

Comment: Yes, that's right @AndyPiper

Answer (score 0):

This is not available in the Twitter API.